# How to deal with table rows with pagination

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

To test all rows in a table, I use this code:

```
driver.find_elements(xpath: "//table//tr").each_with_index  do |_, index|
  next if index.eql?0
  driver.find_element(xpath: "//table//tr[#{index}]/td[1]/a").click
  # some other testing code here
  driver.navigate.back
end
```

When the table is paginated, using my code will stop when reaching the last row of the first page.

Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: You have missed out one line `next if index.eql?0` Go back copy properly this time, okay?

Comment: I have it in my code, just did not post it her, I am going to update it. but still wondering why after every iteration we have to go next only if index is 0 .

Comment: I have written an answer using which you don't have to skip the index 0